# Why is my MAC address invalid?

Tags: macos, networking, router, mac-address

My macbook has this MAC address : 68:A8:6D:09:2A:D4

[This page](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/MAC_Address_Format_Validator.php) tells me that its invalid.

[image]

[This page](http://www.arcai.com/index.php) correctly identifies the brand of the mac address.

[image]

I have a MAC filter for my router and I cannot enter my macbook mac address into my router because it is giving me the same invalid MAC error message.

[image]

What is wrong with my mac address ?

Answer (score 2):

Use lower-case letters like this: 68:a8:6d:09:2a:d4

Comment: Using lower-case validates on the given page. Rather broken design of the regexp I'd say ;)